# R: default value using other argument modified when other argument modified

Tags: r

When defining a default argument `y` to an R function as being equal to an other argument `x`. Ex: `function(x,y=x)`. I found that if I change the other argument (`x`) before using my default argument (`y`), it also changes the value of y.

I understand it has to do with "delayed copying until modified" but is that really the desired behavior?

Hereafter a full example:

```
oh_my <- function(x, y=x){
    x <- rev(x)
    y <- rev(y) # the value of y here actually is rev of initial x!
    print(y)
}
oh_my(1:5)
```

> [1] 1 2 3 4 5

An easy solution would be:

```
ok <- function(x, y=NULL){
    if(is.null(y)){
        y<-x
    }
    x <- rev(x)
    y <- rev(y)
    print(y)
}
ok(1:5)
```

> [1] 5 4 3 2 1

But I actually like the fact that the default is obvious in the first option (including in automatically generated help files).

An other solution would be:

```
pfiouu <- function(x, y=x){
    y <- rev(y) # the value of y here actually is rev of initial x!
    x <- rev(x)
    print(y)
}
```

pfiouu(1:5)

> [1] 5 4 3 2 1

But it really seems awkward to me that `pfiouu` and `oh_my` give different results as the two exchanged lines do not mention explicitly each others variables and yet yield different results!

Am I missing a good practice that would keep the default obvious and avoid that kind of fall-trap?

Comment: You could add a `force(y)` to the start of your function body. That would trigger the evaluation.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick should I add that as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by MrFlick, adding `force(y)` at the start of the function allows to force the evaluation of `y` and prevents issues like that. It being a desirable behavior in such a high level programming language as R remains open though.

```
no_surprise<- function(x, y=x){
    force(y)
    x <- rev(x)
    y <- rev(y) 
    print(y)
}
no_surprise(1:5)
```

> [1] 5 4 3 2 1

As expected.